# Double linked list delete back node function

Tags: function, linked-list

/* There is something wrong with the function delete_back(); I think something wrong with the remove function 3 parts.
    Also remove_ele() I do not how to do it, thanks.
    why I use the same method to delete element does not work
 */

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


template<class T>
class doulinked
{
private:
    doulinked *head;
    doulinked *tail;
    doulinked *prev;
    doulinked *next;

    T data;
public:
    doulinked()
    {
        head=tail=prev=next=NULL;
        T data;
    }
    void Inlist (doulinked *head);
    void add(T d);
    void insert_node();
    void remove(doulinked* v);
    void push_tail(T d); 
    void delete_front();
    void delete_back();
    void remove_ele (T d);
    template <class U>
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, const doulinked<U> & dll);
};
template<class U>
ostream & operator<<(ostream & os,const doulinked<U> & dll)
{
    doulinked<U> * tmp = dll.head;
    while (tmp)
    {
      os << tmp->data << " ";
      tmp = tmp->next;
    }

  return os;
}
template<class T>
void doulinked<T>::add(T d)
{
    doulinked *n = new doulinked;
    n->data=d;
        if( head == NULL)
        {
            head = n;
            tail = n;
        }
        else
        {
            head->prev = n;
            n->next = head;
            head = n;
        }
}
template<class T>
void doulinked<T>::push_tail(T d)
{
    doulinked *n = new doulinked;
    n->data=d;
        if( tail == NULL)
        {
            head = n;
            tail = n;
        }
        else
        {
            tail->next = n;
            n->prev = tail;
            tail = n;
        }

}
template <class T>
void doulinked<T>::delete_front()
{
    remove(head); 
}
template <class T>
void doulinked<T>::delete_back()
{
    remove(tail);
}
template <class T>
void doulinked<T>::remove(doulinked* v) 
{   
    if(v->prev!=NULL && v->next!=NULL)
    {
        doulinked* p = v->prev; 
        doulinked* n = v->next;             
        p->next = n;                
        n->prev = p;
        delete v;
    }
    else if(v->prev==NULL && v->next!=NULL)
    {
        doulinked* n =v->next;             
        head->next = n;                
        n->prev = head;
        delete head;
        head=n;
    }
    else if(v->prev!=NULL && v->next==NULL) // have some wrong with this loop;
    {
        doulinked* p=v->prev;
        p->next=tail;
        tail->prev=p;
        delete tail;
        tail=p;
    }

 }
template <class T>
void doulinked<T>::remove_ele(T d)  // have some wrong with this loop
{

    if(head->data==d)
    {
        remove(head);
        head=head->next;
    }
    else
        head=head->next;
}

int main()
{
    doulinked<int> dll;
    dll.add(5123);
    dll.add(1227);
    dll.add(127);
    dll.push_tail(1235);
    dll.push_tail(834);
    dll.push_tail(1595);
    dll.delete_front();
    //dll.delete_back();
    //dll.remove_ele(834);
    cout<<dll<<endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your design is a little confused.

The traditional C++ way to design a linked list (like `std::list`) has separate `node` and `list` classes, instead of a single class that acts as both:

```
template <typename T> struct node {
    node *prev, *next;
};
template <typename T> struct list {
    node *head, *tail;
};
```

If you want to just pass around `node` pointers, that's fine—but then you have to pass around node *pointers*, not node *objects*. And the mutator functions have to return a pointer as well—if you call `delete_front` on the head node, you've now got a reference to a deleted node; you need its `next` or you've lost any reference to the list. Since the constructor has to return a pointer, you can't use a real public constructor; you want a static factory method instead. And so on.

You also have to be consistent about whether there's a "sentinel node" before the head (and after the tail) or not. If you're creating a sentinel in your constructor—as you are doing—new nodes inserted at the end(s) need to point at the sentinel(s)—which you aren't doing.

Also, the whole `head`/`tail` notion you're using is wrong for a node API. (Also, it's incredibly confusing to mix and match names from different styles—you've got `add` matching `delete_front` and `push_tail` matching `delete_back`…) To have a `push_tail` method, you either have to walk the entire list (making it O(N)), or you have to have every node hold the `tail` pointer (making any list change O(N)), or you have to make the head hold a `tail` pointer and the tail hold a `head` pointer.

The last one works (it wastes a couple of pointers for every node when only one node needs each, but that rarely matters). But it gets confusing to think about.

It's actually a lot simpler to just create a circular list, where the head's `prev` points at the tail (or sentinel) instead of 0, and the tail's `next` points at the head (or sentinel) instead of 0. This gets you all the advantages of a separate `list` class, without needing that class—if you have a pointer to the head, that's all you need to refer to the entire list (because `node` is the head and `node->prev` is the tail, or or similarly if you have a sentinel).

Also, your constructor doesn't make much sense:

```
doulinked()
{
    head=tail=prev=next=NULL;
    T data;
}
```

This creates a local default-constructed `T` variable named `data`, and then… does nothing with it. You probably wanted to set `data` to something. And you probably wanted to use initializers for this. And in that case, you don't need to do anything, because that's already the default.

And I'm not sure what `Inlist` is even supposed to do.

As for `remove_ele(T d)`, presumably you want to remove the first element whose `data == d`, right? If you write a `find` method first, then it's trivial: `remove(find(d))`. (I'm assuming that `find` throws an exception; if you want `find` to return null or the sentinel or something else instead, and `remove_ele` to return `true` or `false`, obviously you need one more line to check whether the find worked.)

If you don't know how to write a `find` method… well, that's kind of the whole point of a linked list, there's a trivial recursive definition for all traversal functions, including `find`:

```
node *node::find(T d) {
    if (data == d) { return this; }
    if (next) { return next->find(d); }
    return 0;
}
```

Anyway, I think rather than try to bang on your code until it works, you should look at existing implementations of the various designs until you understand the differences, then pick the design you want and try to implement that.